# How can I get scaled x ticks=false to work with xbar stacked in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, axis

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
name,a,b
name1,1000,1000000
name2,1000,1000000
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{test.csv}\datatable
  \begin{axis}[
      xbar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
      ytick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
      yticklabels from table={\datatable}{name},
      scaled x ticks=false,
    ]
    \addplot table [x=a,  meta=name, col sep=comma, y expr=\coordindex] {test.csv};
    \addplot table [x=b,  meta=name, col sep=comma, y expr=\coordindex] {test.csv};
    \legend{a,b}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Unlike in normal plots, the x ticks are still scaled.  How do I get them to not be scaled and instead display as things like 200,000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so you can change the `number format` style to `fixed`. But then you get other problems, as you can see in the result below. A way out of that (and staying at that number format) would be to change the ticklabel (font) size, the `axis` `width` or the `tick distance`, which is up to you.

(In addition I did some other refinements to your code, just in case you don't know that stuff.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
name,a,b
name1,1000,1000000
name2,1000,1000000
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % (just to make it look better)
        width=\axisdefaultwidth,
        height=3cm,
        enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
        % ---
        xbar stacked,
        ytick=data,
        % (you can state the file name here as well)
        yticklabels from table={test.csv}{name},
        scaled x ticks=false,
        % with the "number format" you can choose how they show up
        xticklabel style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
        },
        % (moved common stuff here so you don't need to repeat it)
        table/col sep=comma,
        table/y expr=\coordindex,
        table/meta=name,
    ]
        \addplot table [x=a] {test.csv};
        \addplot table [x=b] {test.csv};
        \legend{a,b}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]